# Reorder plot titles for filledcurved

Tags: gnuplot

I have a nice gnuplot graphic in which I want to change the labeling in the key. The problem that I have is related to the filledcurves option. To make things easier, I attached the image. As one can see, the key labeling is 2 - 1 - 3 while I would like to have 1 - 2 - 3 while keeping the same filledcurves pattern. Sure, simply changing the order of my plot, will give me 1 - 2 - 3 but respectively the pattern of the filling changes too and I want to avoid this. I was trying to hack it somehow by using the `NaN` possibilities in gnuplot (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614654/gnuplot-legend-order) but the problem here is that the filling is different. While checking the gnuplot documentation (http://www.bersch.net/gnuplot-doc/filledcurves.html) I realized that there is no option to fix the pattern but I guess there should be some way. For testing, I attached the gnuplot script.

[image]

```
#!/bin/gnuplot
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

set grid
set key right top
set xrange [20:220]

set style line 20 lw 2 lc rgb 'black'
set border linestyle 20
set style line 1 lw 2.0 lc rgb 'dark-gray'
set style line 2 lw 2.0 lc rgb '#202020'
set style line 3 lw 2.0 lc rgb 'gray'
set style fill transparent pattern 2


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A=-1.74959e-14
B=-1.87199e-12
C=1.87756e-9
DeltaBDP=0.45e-9

OffsetBP=0.05e-9
DeltaBP=0.8e-9

OffsetB=0.7e-9
DeltaB=0.8e-9

# 
f(x)=A*x**2+B*x+C
g(x)=f(x)+DeltaBDP

# Beta P
h(x)=f(x)+OffsetBP
i(x)=h(x)+DeltaBP

# Beta
j(x)=h(x)+OffsetB
k(x)=j(x)+DeltaB

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

set terminal epslatex
set output 'tex/foobar.tex'
plot \
'+' using 1:(j($1)*1e9):(k($1)*1e9) with filledcurves closed lc rgb 'dark-gray' t '2' , \
'+' using 1:(f($1)*1e9):(g($1)*1e9) with filledcurves closed lc rgb 'dark-gray' t '1', \
'+' using 1:(h($1)*1e9):(i($1)*1e9) with filledcurves closed lc rgb '#202020' t '3', \
f(x)*1e9 w l ls 1 t '', \
g(x)*1e9 w l ls 1 t '', \
h(x)*1e9 w l ls 2 t '', \
i(x)*1e9 w l ls 2 t '', \
j(x)*1e9 w l ls 3 t '', \
k(x)*1e9 w l ls 3 t ''


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone has the same problem, the solution is simple (as always). After searching for the keyword `pattern` `style` `fill` it was obvious how to deal with that. First, as I already did and @ksyrium also mentioned is to unset the titles in the plots. Subsequent, adding `NaN` plots while choosing the pattern by using `fill pattern <int>`. Doing so, the ordering in the `NaN`plots can be changed as one likes to have it.

```
plot \
'+' using 1:(j($1)*1e9):(k($1)*1e9) with filledcurves closed lc rgb 'dark-gray' t '1real', \
'+' using 1:(f($1)*1e9):(g($1)*1e9) with filledcurves closed lc rgb 'dark-gray' t '2real', \
'+' using 1:(h($1)*1e9):(i($1)*1e9) with filledcurves closed lc rgb '#202020' t '3real', \
f(x)*1e9 w l ls 1 t '', \
g(x)*1e9 w l ls 1 t '', \
h(x)*1e9 w l ls 2 t '', \
i(x)*1e9 w l ls 2 t '', \
j(x)*1e9 w l ls 3 t '', \
k(x)*1e9 w l ls 3 t '', \
NaN with filledcurves closed fill pattern 2 lc rgb 'dark-gray' t '1', \
NaN with filledcurves closed fill pattern 3 lc rgb 'dark-gray' t '2', \
NaN with filledcurves closed fill pattern 4 lc rgb '#202020' t '3'
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it now, but maybe the second answer on this page does work:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290504/reordering-gnuplot

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I did similar things but the problem is, that the filledcurves style is changing. So if I have plot 1 - 3 without title and I add empty plots 4 - 6, then the filling pattern is now the same as in 1 - 3. Unfortunately, I have no glue how to change the filling pattern namely the filledcurves style.